# How to install venv with pip on linux ubuntu 18.04 python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I tried to install `venv` with `pip`, and it gave me the following error message:

this is the command:

```
$ pip install venv
```

and the error:

```
Collecting venv
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/venv/
```

os: linux ubuntu 18.04
python 3.7

Thank you!

Comment: Try `pip install virtualenv`

Comment: are you sure you're using Python 3.7? it says Python 2.7 in the traceback...

Comment: for python3 use `pip3 install virtualenv`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04, `python` executable is [bound by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075203/python-version-in-ubuntu-18-04) to `python2.7` (Which is [now EOL](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)); so when you do:

```sh
pip install venv
```

You're trying to install `venv` on Python2.7 which is only compatible with python3.3+ (see below) and that's why you get those errors.

As a side note, you don't need to install `venv` on `python3.3`+ because it's included by default, see [venv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), but the distribution maintainers may ship Python without this module, so you'll have to install it using your package manager, in this case:

```
sudo apt install python3-venv -y
```

Creation of virtual environments is done by executing the command:

```sh
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

For previous versions of Python (in your case 2.7), you can use `virtualenv`

```sh
pip install virtualenv
```

And the creation:

```sh
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

Note that the `-p` flag is not mandatory, it's just to make sure you're calling the correct Python version in case you installed virtualenv with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: thank you, very helpful :) how can i set python 3.6.8 the default instead of  2.7 ? i need to install "toga" and it requires python 3.4 +

Comment: You can symlink `python` to `python3`, something like `sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: Do not symlink python3 to python. On Ubuntu it will break the system.

Comment: @roye123 You can an alias instead `alias python = /usr/bin/python3`, it won't break your system because only the user calls to python will be affected